# Perl regular expression not responding to $

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Test::Simple tests => 2;    
$file = "lalaletc";
$file2 = "lalal";
ok($file =~ m/^lala/);
ok($file2 =~ m/^lala$/);
```

The output was as following:

```
1..2
ok 1
not ok 2
#   Failed test at ./test.pl line 7.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2.
```

But $file2 has no more characters, so I expected it to succeed test 2. Why does it not?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. It does not merrit a downvote. Everyone makes these mistakes once in a while. We have all been too blind to see a missing letter or semikolon after all.

Comment: This question shows the broken code; it tells us what was tried; it shows the error message; it's clearly written; it has everything we ever ask for in a good question.  The OP may have a limited understanding of REs, but that's why he's here asking for help. It's a good question. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your variable `$file2` is set to `lalal`. That is 5 characters. Your regex is `/^lala$/`, which means:

- beginning of line/string
- lala
- end of line/string

That's only 4 characters because the last `l` is missing. The regex does not match and the test fails. This is correct behaviour.

Try it here:  http://rubular.com/r/O0GhEIiVAZ 
Add the missing `l` at the end and it will match.

Here's some [additional explanation](https://metacpan.org/module/GSULLIVAN/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm) taken from [this site](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%5Elala$):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  lala                     'lala'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Note that for this case, you do not need a regular expression. You can also use the [`eq` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eq.html).

Answer (score 3):

`$` matches end of the string/line in this case. Since there's an outstanding "l" in your string which is not matched, the pattern match fails.